# view pdf in program(delphi) by use free library(not activeX)

Tags: delphi, pdf

Is there are any open source or free-ware library to display PDF file in my Delphi program?

I had looked for one, but most of them are commercial or not fully functional.

PS: this solution need to be cross platform by using wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution might be to include the open source SumatraPDF viewer with your program and use it to display the pdf's.
http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/index.html

One nice thing about SumatraPDF, other than it being open source, is that it doesn't require an install.  It consists solely of a single .exe, so you could just stick the .exe in your app's folder and call it to display pdf's.  SumatraPDF is a pretty bare-bones viewer, so it may be one of the ones you've already looked at and rejected as "not fully functional", but I'm not sure whether you're going to find any perfect open source solution.

As others brought up in the similar thread that was linked from this one, you might consider using the Gnostice library or the WPCubed wpdfviewer component.  You have to purchase a developer's license for those, but then can incorporate them in your app and deploy as many as you want with no runtime licensing fees.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428274/displaying-pdfs-within-a-desktop-app) question discusses the Adobe API.

I missed the PS. Some other answers to the same question may help.